# Why is SSH protocol not connecting to destination successfully?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

In firefox, I can connect to `google.com:80`. But after

```
$ ssh -L 9000:google.com:80 testme@localhost
```

in firefox, I connect to `http://localhost:9000/`, an then

> 404. That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Why is the difference? Thanks.

Comment: What is it you were wishing to accomplish?

Answer (score 7):

Your connection is being correctly established, but your browser is requesting a host and URL (“/” on “localhost:9000”) which the Google servers aren’t configured to handle.

You can see the request using `curl -v`; it will contain at least

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
```

The “Host” line is used to determine which virtual host is being requested (this is one of the additions in HTTP 1.1 compared to 1.0). Google servers aren’t configured with a virtual host for “localhost:9000” so they can’t find the requested resource and reply with a 404 status.

In most cases, if you want to solve a problem with web browsing and you’re thinking of using SSH tunneling, you should use a proxy instead. In some circumstances you might end up use SSH tunneling to forward a proxy’s listening port if necessary; but you typically wouldn’t forward a web server’s listening port using an SSH tunnel.

However, if you want to understand what’s going on here, and make your tunnel usable in a web browser (ignoring the above), you need to ensure that the local host will respond on the same host and port that the target expects, or specify the “Host” header which `curl` should use:

```
curl -H "Host: google.com" http://localhost:9000/
```

With a web browser, you’d specify the IP address rather than host name when creating the tunnel, for example

```
ssh -L 9000:216.58.213.142:443 testme@localhost
```

then add

```
127.0.0.1 google.com www.google.com
```

to your `/etc/hosts` file before visiting `https://google.com:9000` in your browser.

Comment: Thanks. Why In firefox, I can connect to google.com:80, and why not when I use ssh port forwarding?

Comment: @Tim The URL is part of the HTTP request.  The server will look at it to determine how to handle it.  It expects a Google URL, not `localhost:9000`, so it refuses to serve a document and returns 404 instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda Where is "the URL in the HTTP request"? Which line or header? (by curl)

Comment: @Tim The HTTP request would look something like `GET http://localhost:9000/ HTTP/1.1`.  It's a standard GET request.

Comment: Not quite, it’s `GET / HTTP/1.1` followed by a `Host: localhost:9000` line. (It does’t change the problem though.)

Comment: @Kusalananda Does that mean SSH port forwarding is useless for forwarding HTTP request?

Comment: @Tim no, it doesn’t; see my update.

Comment: "if you want web browsing to work using SSH tunneling", how do you "ensure that the local host will respond on the same host and port that the target expects"?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499184/how-can-i-ensure-that-the-local-host-will-respond-on-the-same-host-and-port-tha

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: When you finaly manage to get that through -- you'll notice that google will redirect you to an https url, and then it becomes painfully obvious that all this ssh-redirecting was a pointless exercise (if anybody still had any doubt ;-)).

Comment: @pizdelect not quite pointless, the next step is to forward to port 443 instead of 80...

Comment: And then you'll notice than curl or the browser will refuse to accept the google's cert when coming from localhost.

Comment: @pizdelect seriously, I’ve done it, it works fine.

Comment: That's because you tampered with the resolver to make it return 127.0.0.1 for google.com. You may just as well install your own root certificate in the browser, or hack it to not check the certificate at all.

Comment: @pizdelect no, Google’s certificate is still used and verified.

Comment: `ssh -L 9000:216.58.213.142:443 testme@localhost -N & curl -H "Host: google.com" https://localhost:9000/` will refuse to accept google's cert (for good reason). Of course, you can make it work if you change "localhost" to "google.com", and hack the resolver into returning 127.0.0.1 for google.com, completely breaking your system. But what's the point of all this? `ssh` supports tun/tap device forwarding, etc.

Comment: @pizdelect did you read what I wrote at the end of my answer? You’re describing what I described. I’m not sure what you’re trying to argue about really.

Comment: I've already told you in the 1st comment -- this is not a useful example of ssh redirecting. The fact that you had to change (as root) the `/etc/hosts` file should've rung some bells.

Comment: @StephenKitt Thanks. if a hostname can be resolved in /etc/hosts,
does DNS still apply to resolve the hostname or its resolved IP address by /etc/hosts?

Comment: No, it doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks. WHy 'specify the IP address rather than host name when creating the tunnel"?