# Why should I "specify the IP address rather than host name when creating the tunnel"?

Tags: ssh

In my previous post asking about [Why is SSH protocol not connecting to destination successfully?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498784/why-is-ssh-protocol-not-connecting-to-destination-successfully) 
my original command is

```
ssh -L 9000:google.com:80 testme@localhost
```

To solve the problem, Stephen Kitt wrote

> With a web browser, you’d specify the IP address rather than host name
>   when creating the tunnel, for example
>
> ```
> ssh -L 9000:216.58.213.142:80 testme@localhost
> ```

I was wondering why to "specify the IP address rather than host name when creating the tunnel"?

If  google.com is resolved to 216.58.213.142, aren't the two commands the same?

Is it something about the difference between IP address and virtual host?

Thanks.

Comment: A DNS lookup isn't performed when using IP addresses...

Comment: Thanks. How does not performing DNS lookup help to solve the problem in the linked post?

Comment: _If_ name resolving matches then... yes.  But be aware that name resolving may be compromised (eg via `/etc/hosts` entries, broken DNS servers, bad `nsswitch.conf` settings...).  Using IP addresses will ensure they have no impact.  FWIW, I get `216.58.217.142` for `google.com`; a different IP address.

Answer (score 1):

> If google.com is resolved to 216.58.213.142, aren't the two commands the same?

Yes, but the point here is to deal with situations where google.com doesn’t resolve to a Google IP address, as happens after you edit `/etc/hosts`. By specifying the IP address (which you determine by performing your own DNS lookup, to get a valid IP address, and in Google’s case a geographically-appropriate IP address), you ensure that the tunnel is set up as you expect it, without having to check `/etc/hosts` or any other resolution mechanism first. SSH resolves and opens connections to forwarded ports as necessary; if you forward a port to a hostname and then override that hostname’s address, SSH will attempt to forward connections to the overridden address, not the address you’re expecting.